# combine two list based on a unique value in both list

Tags: date-and-time, list-manipulation

Problem: I want to add a column-value from list A into list B based on a unique value in both list. The unique value in both list is not the same column. Both list have a different structure.

for example:

```
data1 = {{DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], 1, A}, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 02}], 2,A}, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 03}], 1, A}, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 04}], 3, F}};

data2 = {3,72, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], keep, 1, 2, 3}, {3, 72,DateObject[{2020, 01, 02}], keep, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 72,DateObject[{2020, 01, 03}], sell, 1, 5, 7}, {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 04}], sell, 3, 5 , 9}, {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 05}], sell, 4, 6, 9}};
```

I want to combine both list based on the DateObject. The desired output is like:

```
output = {3, 72, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], keep, 1, 2, 3, A}, {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 02}], keep, 2, 3, 4, A}, {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 03}], sell, 1, 5, 7, A}, {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 04}], sell, 3, 5 , 9, F}}
```

What is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: You have a syntax error in `data2` here with the extra `{` like this `{3,72, {DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], keep, 1, 2, 3}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = {
   {DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], 1, A},
   {DateObject[{2020, 01, 02}], 2, A},
   {DateObject[{2020, 01, 03}], 1, A},
   {DateObject[{2020, 01, 04}], 3, F}
   };
data2 = {
   {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 01}], keep, 1, 2, 3},
   {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 02}], keep, 2, 3, 4},
   {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 03}], sell, 1, 5, 7},
   {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 04}], sell, 3, 5, 9},
   {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 01, 05}], sell, 4, 6, 9}
   };
assocData1 = AssociationThread[data1[[All, 1]] -> data1[[All, -1]]];
result = With[{date = #[[3]]}, If[KeyExistsQ[assocData1, date], 
     Append[#, assocData1[date]], Nothing]] & /@ data2
```

The result:

```
{
  {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], keep, 1, 2, 3, A}, 
  {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 1, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], keep, 2, 3, 4, A},
  {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 1, 3}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], sell, 1, 5, 7, A}, 
  {3, 72, DateObject[{2020, 1, 4}, "Day", "Gregorian", 1.], sell, 3, 5, 9, F}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
assoc = AssociationThread[data1[[All, 1]], data1[[All, -1]]];

output2 = Select[FreeQ[_Missing]][data2 /. 
     {a___, d_DateObject, b___} :> {a, d, b, assoc[d]}];

output2 == output
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

For the example in OP, using using the first two columns of `data1` as key also gives the same output:

```
assocB = AssociationThread[data1[[All, {1, 2}]], data1[[All, -1]]]
```

[image]

```
output2B = Select[FreeQ[_Missing]][
   data2 /. {a___, d_DateObject, b__} :> {a, d, b, assocB[{d, {b}[[2]]}]}];

output2B == output
```

> ```
>  True
> ```